# SearchView back to search results implementation

Tags: android, searchview

I have a `SearchView` in my `ActionBar` that filters results and shows in a `ListView`. Once the user clicks on an item, I start a new activity to show the details of the item. When they hit the back button, I want to show filtered search results. The search phrase they typed stays in SearchView.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

In my app, I had a few ways to get the search results into the search results activity. If the search activity was sending in the results, I would check for the results in the `Intent` extras. If an orientation change occurred, I would repopulate the search results using `savedInstanceState`, and if I navigate to the details activity, then come back again, I repopulate the search results from a saved file. So my `onCreate()` code has a structure like this:

```
if(savedInstanceState != null) {
    terms = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList(TERM_RESULTS_KEY);
} else {
    Bundle args = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(args != null) {
        resultsData = args.getParcelableArrayList(SearchActivity.SEARCH_RESULT_ARGS);
        //...
    } else {
        terms = getSavedResults();
    }
}
```

When I navigate away from the activity (like going to a details page, as you mentioned), I save the search results like this:

```
private void saveResults(ArrayList<String> results) {
    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = openFileOutput(SAVED_RESULTS_FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
        out.writeObject(results);
        out.close();
        fileOutputStream.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Since `ArrayList` is serializable, it's pretty easy to just write to disk using an `ObjectOutputStream`. Then when the user hits the back button on your details activity, you would retrieve the previous search results like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private ArrayList<String> getSavedResults() {
    ArrayList<String> savedResults = null;

    try {
        FileInputStream inputStream = openFileInput(SAVED_RESULTS_FILENAME);
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);
        savedResults = (ArrayList<String>) in.readObject();
        in.close();
        inputStream.close();

    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return savedResults;
}
```